# Appcelerator Dynamic Config

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app using the latest tools from Appcelerator. I have a dynamic variable that I want to reference via the `Alloy.CFG` global variable. To do this, I added the variable to the `config.json` file for the corresponding environments, however I cannot get the app to read this variable. For example, I tried adding the `--env` flag to the `appc run` command, but that does not work.

Furthermore I cannot find a way to add new environments. I want to add a "qa" environment, however when I add that to the `config.json` file and use `appc run --env=qa` it gives me an error saying `unknown environment named 'qa'`. How can I add more environments and how do I get the `appc run` command to read the variables for the specific configuration???

Answer (score 0):

In config json u will have to mention some thing like this

```
"env:development" : {
}, 
"env:test" : {
}
```